# Is it possible to call in some way an EJB deployed on JBoss from a Business Service deployed on BEA AquaLogic Service Bus?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, bea, alsb

Is it possible to call in some way an EJB deployed on JBoss from a Business Service deployed on BEA AquaLogic Service Bus?
Just to precise, I'm not going to call it through Web Service, but through normal EJB call. I would appreciate if anyone has a succesful experience in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Its irrelevant whether the client of an EJB is itself an application server or not.  As long as a shared (or available) JNDI service (that the EJB is bound to) is accessible to your service bus, it an act as a client of the EJB published by the (JBoss) application server.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your JBoss EJB with RMI and call it from AquaLogic, provided your EJB implements some interface that is available from AquaLogic.